# Is it possible to add spacing to a Ribbon Icon through manifest file in an Office JS Addin?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am making an office js addin. I have added some buttons on the Ribbon through the manifest file and I am wondering if it is possible to set the icon's width so that the result is more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have icons of various widths. Microsoft requires that you have icons in sizes 16x16, 32x32, and 80x80. Here's a snippet from a manifest that illustrates this:

```
<Icon>
    <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
    <!--Icons. Required sizes: 16, 32, 80; optional: 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. You should provide as many sizes as possible for a great user experience. -->
    <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
</Icon>
```

Then in the Resources section:

```
<Resources>
    <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button16x16.png" />
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button80x80.png" />
    </bt:Images>
...
</Resources>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this feature. I have set 3 different icons sizes for all icons (16,32 & 80 px). I am just wondering if it is possible to add some spacing between the icons manually. Either by setting a width attribute or by adding some xml space characters like #x0020

Comment: Please revise your question to clarify exactly what you are really asking for. You said "set the icon's width" in the question, but said "spacing between the icons" in your comment above. These are not the same thing.  It is not possible to add spacing.

Comment: thanks Rick. You are right, I have re-phrased my question.